# how to do lookup and filter data on the same table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, sql-null

In SQL, where we need to filter the unnecessary data from a table:

- case 1: if 2 IDs are same and DOD is not null then Record is needed
- case 2: if single id is there and dod is not null then Record is needed
- case 3: if 2 ids are same and if DOD is null for any one of them ,then record is not needed

[image]

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use analytic functions for this:

```
select t.*
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        sum(case when dod is null then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id) no_nulls
    from mytable t
) t
where no_nulls = 0
```

Note that this also excludes records that have no duplicate `id` but whose `dod` is `null` (you did not describe how to handle those).

You could also use `not exists` (which can conviniently be turned to a `delete` statement if needed):

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists(select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.dod is null)
where no_nulls = 0
```